# Resizing my simple OpenGL/GLUT window creates strange lines

Tags: c++, opengl, resize, window, glut

I recently created my first GLUT window and gave it a white background and somewhere for a camera to look at.

Anyway, I resize my window and I got these strange lines. It seemed like it glitched and captured recent fragments of my desktop screen. Here is my screenshot link on imgur:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdr6Z.png

Sorry if the picture was a little oversized, but I was wondering if there was a fix to that weird glitch.

Here is my code:

```
#include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
#include <GLUT/GLUT.h>
void display(void) {
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt (0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glFlush();
}   

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 400);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("My First GLUT/OpenGL Window");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You get those weird glitches because you don't resize your viewport. What you need to do is create a callback function for [glutReshapeFunc](https://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node48.html) in which you call glViewport to resize your viewport. Then, you need to call glutPostRedisplay in order to re-execute your display function.

On a side note, if you want your display function to be executed constantly, use glutIdleFunc along side glutDisplayFunc.

Cheers!

Comment: Hello, I tried your code, but a new problem occurred. I was debating whether or not to put it in a new question, but I decided to put it here. I tried running the code but the window doesn't appear. In the bottom of Xcode it says "GDB: Program loaded" and "Succeeded", but the window refuses to show. Sorry for bothering you but what is the problem?

Comment: Try using glutIdleFunc as well as glutDisplayFunc. My bad.

Comment: Thanks for replying;

Nothing seems to work, the program seems to have run successfully, and there are no build errors, but the only problem is that the window doesn't show up.

Comment: You should not set the viewport in the resize handler. You can find this practice often in tutorials, but it leads to problems later. Set the viewport at the beginning of the display function and retrieve the window size using `glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH);` `glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT);` – trust me, about doing it this way, you'll thank me later.